Frame of PushButton is cut off when using fractional DPR
I recently updated a piece of software from Qt 5.15 to Qt 6.5. The process itself was easier than expected but the new handling of high-DPI scaling in lead to some visual errors on multiple Widgets, mainly visible on the PushButtons which is why I will focus on them.
These Buttons are based on QPushButton and have their paintEvent overwritten like this:
    QPainter p(this);
    p.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    //Set clip path
    QPainterPath bgRectPath;
    bgRectPath.addRoundedRect(this->rect(), rectRadius, rectRadius);

    p.setClipPath(bgRectPath);

    //Draw background
    p.fillPath(bgRectPath, QBrush(backgroundColor));

    //Draw Frame
    QScreen *screen = this->screen();
    qreal dpr = screen->devicePixelRatio();
    qreal scaledLineWidth = lineWidth * ceil(dpr);

    QPen framePen = QPen(lineColor, scaledLineWidth);
    framePen.setCosmetic(true);

    p.setPen(framePen);
    p.drawPath(bgRectPath);

    //Draw Label
    QFont font = p.font();
    font.setPixelSize(labelFontSize);
    p.setFont(font);
    p.setPen(fontColor);

    p.drawText(rect(), labelAlign, label);

I have already adjusted the paintEvent such that the line width is not fractional which lead to a whole other set of issues. Instead, the line width is scaled manually with ceil(dpr) and by using a cosmetic QPen.
This has solved the visual errors for some of the buttons but not for all of them. The remaining issues appear to be connected to the QLayouts these buttons are in and this is where the inconsistency starts to arise. Here are three examples of buttons all in Layouts using margins of 0, 0, 0, 0:
These buttons are perfectly fine

This button is cut off on the left

These buttons are cut off on the top

Except adding the buttons and changing the margins I set the alignment to Qt::AlignRight and the spacing to 10. Removing the alignment does not solve the issue either.
As one can see, some buttons are cut off on either the left or the top. This may be fixed by changing the margins of the layout to e.g. 1, 0, 0, 0 or 0, 1, 0, 0 respectively. But the consistency does not end yet: Sometimes one pixel margin is not enough and 2-3 pixels are required. Also, when buttons which are fine using a zero margin on all sides do receive a margin they are cut off as a consequence.
I have thought about implementing all these margins manually but fear that the behavior may change as soon as another scaling factor or display resolution is used.
Is there a consistent way to prevent these Widgets from being cut off? The easiest method is probably to adjust the HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy so there are no fractional DPRs but I would like to prevent this if possible.
Here is the code required to replicate the cut off button on the left side (using a usable monitor resolution of 3840 x 2160 and a scaling of 150%). I built it using Qt 6.5.5 MinGW 64-bit.
main.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}


mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLayout>
#include "custombutton.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H


mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget *widget = new QWidget;

    CustomButton *button = new CustomButton;

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addSpacing(5);
    layout->addWidget(button);
    layout->addSpacing(5);
    layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);     //Left side is cut off
    // layout->setContentsMargins(1, 0, 0, 0);     //Left side is not cut off

    widget->setLayout(layout);
    setCentralWidget(widget);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {}


custombutton.h
#ifndef CUSTOMBUTTON_H
#define CUSTOMBUTTON_H

#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPainterPath>
#include <QScreen>

class CustomButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CustomButton();

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;
};

#endif // CUSTOMBUTTON_H


custombutton.cpp
#include "custombutton.h"

CustomButton::CustomButton() {}

void CustomButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    p.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    //Set clip path
    QPainterPath bgRectPath;
    bgRectPath.addRoundedRect(rect(), 0.5*rect().height(), 0.5*rect().height());

    p.setClipPath(bgRectPath);

    //Draw Frame
    QScreen *screen = this->screen();
    qreal dpr = screen->devicePixelRatio();
    qreal scaledLineWidth = 1.0 * ceil(dpr);

    QPen framePen = QPen(Qt::black, scaledLineWidth);
    framePen.setCosmetic(true);

    p.setPen(framePen);
    p.drawPath(bgRectPath);

    event->accept();
}



Changing the layout margins shouldn't affect the painting of the widget, but using non integer ratios (eg. 1.5) may have odd and unexpected results. In any case, QPen based drawing always extend half the pen width from the coordinates: if the rect is (0, 0, 100, 100) and the pen width is 2, the bounding rect would be (-1, -1, 102, 102), so you should always consider that aspect; for instance, the reference rectangle for the drawn rounded rect should be rect().adjusted(p, p, -p, -p) (where p is half the pen width), or, more correctly, QRectF(rect()).adjusted(p, p, -p, -p).

Also note that, unless you really need clipped painting due to complex compositing, there should be no need for setClipPath(). In any case, non-integer factors may always lead to drawing artifacts (see the notes on the High DPI), unless extreme care is used. I'm not completely sure, but it's possible that checking the global position of the widget may help in finding a way to compensate. That said, though, setting the rounding policy may be the only reliable and viable option.

Thanks for the propsal, I will try to adjust the rect used for drawing accoringly and give an update asap. Concerning the clip path: It is required for the rounded rect, otherwise the semi circles have artifacts.

What artifacts? That shouldn't happen ,but may be caused by the scaling or the device pixel. I'd suggest to also include that in your update, as may be an issue worth reporting, possibly indirectly caused by your code. Specifically, rounded rects have some drawing artifact if the radii of two adjacent corners is larger than the actual length of the side they refer to (for example, setting a radius to 5 when the side is less than 10).

musicamante said:

Changing the layout margins shouldn't affect the painting of the widget, but using non integer ratios (eg. 1.5) may have odd and unexpected results. In any case, QPen based drawing always extend half the pen width from the coordinates: if the rect is (0, 0, 100, 100) and the pen width is 2, the bounding rect would be (-1, -1, 102, 102), so you should always consider that aspect; for instance, the reference rectangle for the drawn rounded rect should be rect().adjusted(p, p, -p, -p) (where p is half the pen width), or, more correctly, QRectF(rect()).adjusted(p, p, -p, -p).

This appears to have solved the issue in its entirety. I have changed the creation of the QPainterPath using the rect() of the object to using an adjusted rect:
QRectF(rect()).adjusted(scaledLineWidth/2, scaledLineWidth/2, -scaledLineWidth/2, -scaledLineWidth/2)

It appears to also work using a regular (adjusted) QRect.
It also looks as if using a clip path is no longer necessary as of the update to Qt 6. In Qt 5.12.15 this has lead to ugly circles which were prevented using these clip paths. I have since removed them, although the frame looks fine either way.
The paintEvent now looks like this:
QPainter p(this);
p.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing);

//Create the painting path
QScreen *screen = this->screen();
qreal dpr = screen->devicePixelRatio();
qreal scaledLineWidth = lineWidth * ceil(dpr);
QRectF mainRect = QRectF(rect()).adjusted(scaledLineWidth/2, scaledLineWidth/2, -scaledLineWidth/2, -scaledLineWidth/2);

QPainterPath bgRectPath;
bgRectPath.addRoundedRect(mainRect , rectRadius, rectRadius);

//Draw background
p.fillPath(bgRectPath, QBrush(backgroundColor));

//Draw Frame
QPen framePen = QPen(lineColor, scaledLineWidth);
framePen.setCosmetic(true);

p.setPen(framePen);
p.drawPath(bgRectPath);

//Draw Label
QFont font = p.font();
font.setPixelSize(labelFontSize);
p.setFont(font);
p.setPen(fontColor);

p.drawText(mainRect , labelAlign, label);

